# how to use text_field_value_set method in pageobject

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

presently I am using `.send_keys` which doesn't clears the existing text in the field. I find that there is a `text_field_value_set` method available in PageObject which clears existing text and enters link `.set` in watir-webdriver. But i am getting an syntax error when using like this

### Method:

```
def search(job)
    search_job
    wait_element.when_not_visible
    #keyword_element.send_keys "#{job}"
    text_field_value_set(name: 'keyword', "#{job}") # using like this give an error
    add_element.click   
end
```

### Error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => text_field_value_set(name: 'keyword', "#{job}")
                                                              ^ (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get `text_field_value_set` to work**

The error occurs because of the way parameters are being sent to the `text_field_value_set` method.

The method expects two parameters - `text_field_value_set(identifier, value)`. Notice that you are sending trying to send a hash to the first parameter (ie identifier) and a string to the second parameter (value). It is not clear to Ruby where the hash ends. [Skorks](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/more-advanced-ruby-method-arguments-hashes-and-blocks/) has a nice article about the niceness and problems with using hashes as method arguments.

Ultimately it comes down to, if the hash is not the last argument, you need to use an explicit hash - eg putting curly braces around the inputs. This would look like:

```
text_field_value_set({name: 'keyword'}, "#{job}")
```

This will address the exception you are seeing, however you will get another exception about the `text_field_value_set` method not existing. It is a method of the Platform class, which your page is not. However, your page can access the platform with a `platform` method.

Putting it all together, the method will work as:

```
def search(job)
  search_job
  wait_element.when_not_visible
  platform.text_field_value_set({name: 'keyword'}, "#{job}")
  add_element.click   
end
```

**Better solution**

That said, I do not think using `text_field_value_set` is the right approach. This is really more of an internal method that is used by the text field accessors. As well, it defeats the purpose of having the page object accessor methods.

Given that you had a `keyword_element.send_keys`, I assume you have already defined an accessor for the text field:

```
text_field(:keyword, :name => 'keyword')
```

This would have created a method for your page object that allows setting of the text field with the following. This method calls the `text_field_value_set` method, which ultimately calls the desired Watir `set` method.

```
keyword=(value)
```

Your method could be written as:

```
def search(job)
  search_job
  wait_element.when_not_visible
  self.keyword = job
  add_element.click   
end
```

Note that because the `keyword=` method is being used within the class, we need to use `self` so that it is clear we want to make a method call rather than create a local variable.